# How to pass !~ (not) case to awk pattern via a bash shell variable

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following file called file.txt.

```
a,b,c,d
d,c,b,a
```

I want to run the following file called test.txt:

```
#!/bin/bash

data=$(cat file.txt)

gib () {
        echo "$1" | awk -v var="$2" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {if ($1 var~ a) {print $0}}'
}

ti=$(!)

gib "${data}" "$ti"
```

My goal is to only print:

```
d,c,b,a
```

Generally speaking how can I exclude rather than include the awk pattern. I have tried this with /a/ and $1 var~ /a/ without the if construct. But nothing works.

Comment: You can't put operators in variables. It doesn't reparse the expression after substituting the variable.

Comment: What is `a` supposed to be? Did you mean `/a/`?

Comment: What is `$(!)` supposed to mean? That will try to execute `!` as a shell command, but it's not a valid command. Did you mean `ti='!'`?

Comment: if you want to exclude first field matching `a`, why do you expect `a,b,c,d` as the output? If there some fundamental misunderstanding?

Comment: You are right karakfa. Sorry, I corrected it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put operators, or parts of operators, in variables.

If you want to make it conditional whether it looks for a match or non-match, you can take advantage of the fact that the result of a comparison is either 1 or 0, for true or false. So pass in the result you want to test for.

```
#!/bin/bash

data=$(cat file.txt)

gib () {
    echo "$1" | awk -v var="$2" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} ($1 ~ /a/) == var'
}

ti=0

gib "${data}" "$ti"
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can do what you're asking to do:

```
$ cat test.txt
#!/bin/bash

data=$(cat file.txt)

gib () {
        echo "$1" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {if ($1 '"$2"'~ /a/) {print $0}}'
}

ti='!'

gib "${data}" "$ti"
```

```
$ ./test.txt
d,c,b,a
```

but I wouldn't particularly recommend letting a shell variable expand to become part of an awk script, see [@Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77803881/1745001) for one possible better approach to this problem and see [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) for how to use the values of shell variables in awk scripts in general.

Comment: I'll upvote, with the caveat that `gib` should verify that `$2` is *exactly* empty or `!` before attempting to execute the resulting `awk` script.

Comment: (You could also let `var` be some other string that `awk` uses to select one of two hard-coded operations.)

Answer (score 0):

> Generally speaking how can I exclude rather than include the awk
> pattern.

If you wish to skip line matching pattern you might use [`next`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Next-Statement.html) statement, consider following simple example, let `file.txt` be spaced-sheared file with following content

```
qw 1
er 2
ty 3
ui 4
op 5
```

and you wish to print 2nd column values whilst ignoring lines where 1st column starts with vowel (understand as one off: aieou) then you might do it by

```
awk '$1~/^[aieou]/{next}{print $2}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
1
3
```

Explanation: if 1st column starts with one one of `aieou` go to `next` line preventing any action after it from execution, which in this case is `print` 2nd field.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '
a,b,c,d
d,c,b,a' |
```

---

```
awk NF==1 FS='^a,'
```

---

```
d,c,b,a
```

Set whatever "not case" as your `FS`. Then the only way it doesn't match is when no extra columns are being split out, i.e. `NF == 1`